# Fix Android Studio Corrupted Project Workspace Settings

Tags: android, android-studio

I had this problem for a while and was able to solve it myself

If in opening your project in **Android Studio** and something similar to this error message pops up:

> Load Settings
>                  Cannot load settings from file 'C:\Users\sivin.AndroidStudio1.5\config\options\colors.scheme.xml':
>   content truncated
>                  File content will be recreated

Comment: so you don't need any assistance?

Answer (score 3):

1. Close Android Studio
2. Make that file backup somewhere
3. Now delete that file
4. And finally start the Android Studio